# Theme Installation error

Tags: magento-2.1

I am installing theme `ves fasony` and getting below error:

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface
>   Magento\Framework\Url\RouteParamsPreprocessorInterface in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php
>   on line 73

Help me to fix this

Comment: What are steps you are following to install theme?